# Hadoop 2.6 job tacker URL

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have a single node setup of hadoop 2.6.0 on my laptop.My mapred-site.xml has the job tract set at port 9010

I am not able to access the job tracker(not found error) using the following URL after the job has executed- http://localhost:9010

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: For Hadoop 2.x shouldnt you be hitting the resource manger url? There is no jobtracker in Hadoop 2.x

Comment: Thanks, That clarifies. I did hit the resource manager url but I am not able to see my mapreduce logs. The problem is that I am using hadoop streaming to run a python mapper which has syntax errors but the job runs without any errors apparently. Where I can I find the logs for mapper?